# How do I create an event bus using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, event-handling, listener

So, I have a script I made that tracks twitter follows. The bulk of the script's work is done in two parts. One function `track_user(old_followers: dict, screen_name: str) -> dict`, where `dict` contains information about new followers and unfollowers. The second function takes the `dict` from that first function, parses it, and converts it to text that makes sense.

My predicament is: I want other users of this script to be able to insert their own separate from my own code.

I'll give an example below

```py
# My code

def track_user(old_followers: dict, screen_name: str) -> dict:
    final_dict = tracking_code_here()
    SomeEventBus.emit(TrackUserEvent(final_dict))
    return final_dict

# Some user's code (using my example above as an example)
def convert_tracking_to_text(event: TrackUserEvent): 
    perform_some_text_conversion(event.final_dict)
    return

# Maybe a decorator can be used in this case instead
MyScript.EventBus.AddListener(TrackUserEvent, convert_tracking_to_text)
```

Hopefully, this makes sense. I just want my script to emit events that others can import and listen to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some time ago a [library](https://github.com/HerveZu/asyevent) for handling async events. Basically you could do things such as

```py
# creates a main event manager
manager = EventManager()

# creates an event
track_user_event = manager.create_event("track_user_event")

async def track_user(old_followers: dict, screen_name: str) -> dict:
    final_dict = tracking_code_here()
    
    # emit event here
    await track_user_event(TrackUserEvent(finalDict)) # could also be await manager.raise_event("track_user_event");

    return final_dict

@track_user_event.as_callback()
async def convert_tracking_to_text(event: TrackUserEvent): 
    perform_some_text_conversion(event.final_dict)
    return
```

It's far away to be perfect but I hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for linking your library. I ended up going with a smaller library, but yours would've worked well for my use case as well. It has a lot more options which I appreciate. I'll keep it in mind for future purposes

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the other answer because it was useful and did answer the question, but I used the [event-bus](https://github.com/seanpar203/event-bus) library instead.

e.g

```py
def do_query():
    # Announce that user query starting
    MAIN_BUS.emit(events.StartQueryEvent.EVENT_NAME)
    query_users_events = []

    for usr in USERS_TO_QUERY:
        this_user = some_query(usr)
        # Emit event for this specific user
        MAIN_BUS.emit(events.TwitterUserFollowingQuery.EVENT_NAME, this_user)

        # Keeping track of all queried users
        query_users_events.append(this_user)

    # Emit an event with data of all queried users
    MAIN_BUS.emit(events.FinishAllQueryEvents.EVENT_NAME, query_users_events)
```

Then in another file,

```py
# Compare old followers/mutuals to current mutuals after all query events are completed
@bus.on(events.FinishAllQueryEvents.EVENT_NAME)
def keep_track(user_data: list[events.TwitterUserFollowingQuery]):
    some_logic_based_on_data(user_data)
```

[Full example repo](https://github.com/Kyu/follower-tracker)